# How to remove space in between text or list tile and box decoration border in flutter?

Tags: flutter, alignment

I have a problem where I want to create border and rounded box for my drawer list item. I could manage to create the border and rounded box but the problem there is too much space between the text and icon and the surrounding box.

I have tried few ways purely using the container, container and the list tile all gives me the same results. I have tried to play around the padding also the same too.
Below are different codings.

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
       //Padding(padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 10, 10)), 
       Container(
         height: 55,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),

        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
        ),

        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[

                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                        onPressed: () => {},
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0)),
                      Text("TEST"),
                    ],
                  ),
          ]
        ),
       ),
       Container(
       margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
       alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,


       child: ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.map),
            title: Text("Map View"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),

          ),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(

        color: getColor(title,"Dashboard"),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular( 8.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular( 8.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular( 8.0),
        )
        ),

        ),
        Ink(
          color: getColor(title,"Dashboard"),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.map),
            title: Text("Map View"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),

          ),
        ),
         Padding(padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 10, 10)), 
        ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.map),
          title: Text("Map View"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),

        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.map,color: Colors.blue,),
          title: Text("List View"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),

        ),
      ],
)
```

I have attached the image output too.I prefer like the second option but too much space in the box and the words?[image]

[image]

Here is my updated codes.

Column(children: [

```
          Container(

padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),

                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: getColor(title,"Dashboard"),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.amber),
                  ),
                  child:Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.map),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Map View"),
                      Expanded(child: Container (),),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),]
                      )

        ),
        Container(

padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),

                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: getColor(title,"Dashboard"),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.amber),
                  ),
                  child:Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.map),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Map View"),
                      Expanded(child: Container (),),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),]
                      )

        ),
        ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to drop `ListTile` in favour of a custom `Row`.

```dart
Row(children: [
Icon(Icons.map),
SizedBox(width: 10),
Text("Map View"),
Expanded(child: Container (),),
 Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),])
```

(Sorry for the messy code as I'm typing this on my phone.)

With this, you can have more control over your padding and how much space between your Widgets in your row.

Comment: @demos but I need more of this cause is a drawer so u suggest to add manually the row? So there is no way in ListTile to achieve it is ?

Comment: @What I need is that the background like the amber to be only shown for the selected item in the drawer

Comment: To my limited knowledge, there isn't. Maybe someone can correct me on that. I've used ListTile extensively on a few projects but they were quite limited as you noticed.

Comment: @You mean limited in terms of doing the spacing etc is it ?

Comment: @So based on my image how to achieve the background rounded corner when the item is selected

Comment: Yes. I suppose it has a built-in padding that you cannot control. Or it might as well be the padding of the widgets inside of it. My answer is just an alternative which I think It'll work just as well. If you want the onTap property, wrap the whole thing with a GestorDetector.

Comment: The rounded border is exactly how you made it. A Container with a BoxDecoration specifying the borderRadius property.

Comment: @demos can you check my updated codes ? What I did I have big column and in it I keep adding container and the design fits. The only issue there is a big space between the container? Is it something to do with colum ?

Comment: Maybe edit the padding property? I don't know if I'm understanding your issue well enough.

Comment: @Demos I have uploaded my latest picture can you see the first row it has quite a sum of space at top

Comment: Can you see between the grey area and the amber I want to further decrease that space how to do that ?

Comment: If by grey area, you mean the space between the two tiles, then that is controlled by the margin you set to 10. If you want a margin just on one side, use EdgeInsets.only.

Comment: no i mean from the top of the grey area I dont want any top space I want the row to start with no space on top between the grey area and the first row?